# Connect ACF field + custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

Given:
1) Advanced Custom Fields. A select field with predefined values.
2) Custom taxonomy of the custom post type.

Q:
Can I link a selection in the ACF field for automatic taxonomy assignment?
For example: if I select "1" in the ACF field, then "1" will be selected automatically in the taxonomy when updating the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the taxonomy field.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/taxonomy/

You can define which taxonomy to handle and how the appearance should work...

[image]

Which is awesome, because you optionally can use `radio` or `select` if you don't want the user to set more than one taxonomy term per post.

Make sure you always set this to true if you want it work as you have described.

[image]

You can then define in your custom taxonomy code args `'show_ui' => false`. This will hide the default taxonomy metabox, so you only your acf taxonomy metabox can be used.